# Install Cassandra Error: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Cannot open file /usr/.../gc.log

Tags: java, database, cassandra

I'm trying to install Apache Cassandra.

Following the steps from [here](https://medium.com/@manishyadavv/how-to-install-cassandra-on-mac-os-d9338fcfcba4) and altering them slightly:

1. `brew install java`
2. `brew tap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk`
3. `brew install adoptopenjdk8`
4. `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`
5. `export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_282`
6. `brew install cassandra`
7. `cassandra`

[ERROR]

8. `cqlsh`

I got this error when trying to start Cassandra with `cassandra`:
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Cannot open file /usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.10/libexec/logs/gc.log due to No such file or directory

Versions:

- Cassandra 3.11.10
- Python 3.9.2
- Java 8
- MacOS 11.2.3

If anyone has experience with installing Cassandra and has an idea of why this is happening, I'd really appreciate if you could let me know your thoughts. I don't see many other posts with this issue.

**[EDIT]**

I gave up on the MacOS version and decided to just install it in Ubuntu since I found others were finding similar bugs in MacOS.

Comment: What chipset do you have, Intel or M1?

Comment: I have Intel (Macbook Pro 2018)

Comment: Does the path /usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.10/libexec/logs exist and is it writable?

Comment: The `logs` folder didn't exist so I tried creating one but I got another error.

Comment: I have installed and run it fine on MacOS with multiple versions, but installing from the tar file, not with brew. I suspect the issues you're having are due to the brew configuration.